# How can I run multiple queries in sqlBatch sqlite database on ionic3?

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I have three select queries and I want run all at once using sqlite sqlBatch in ionic3. Following are sample queries.

```
sql1 = "select * from projects";
sql2 = "select * from user_comments"
sql3 = "select * from notes"

db.sqlBatch([], function() { 

}, function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

How can I run all the three queries in sqlBatch.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: how do you plan on getting the result of each if you do it with batch?

Comment: I want to create an array of results.

Comment: https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage#using-plugin-specific-api-calls